# Setting a td so that it links to javascript with onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is my html:

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <table id="table1">
        <tr>
            <th>Table</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="1">
                <div>
                    <span>
                        Link 1
                    </span>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<div id="box">
    <img src="iow panorama.png" id="one"/>
    <img src="iow panorama 2.png" id="two"/>
</div>
```

And my CSS:

```
#sidebar {
    display: inline-block;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    font-family: Garamond;
    font-size: large;
}

#table1 {
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
}

#table1 th {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#table1 td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#box {
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
    width: 1200px;
}

#box #one,#two {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}

#one {
    visibility: hidden;
}

#two {
    visibility: hidden;
}

#1 {
    background-color:red;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

And Javascript:

```
$("#1").click(function(){
    var z = parseInt($("#one").css("z-index"));
    z =+ 10;
    $("#one").css("z-index", z);
})
```

Now what I want to happen is the cursor to change to a pointer over the td, and when it is clicked, it triggers the javascript which makes the first image visible but not the second as they are overlayed. Also, the td isn't changing color, even though the CSS should be making it red. What I think is happening is the whole thing is failing at the table/td part of it. How can I fix it so that all of it works? (Also, how do I set the javascript to cause the z-index of the second image to decrease, so I can use another link in the table to create a kind of slideshow, with links to choose the image?)

Comment: Note, the most pressing issue, which may allow me to fix things myself is why isn't the #1 properties in the CSS causing the background color to change for the table cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better to provide id for the link than providing id for td

Also as you are going to make a link ( tag)it will automatically have cursor:pointer css.

It would be even better to use rel tags to relate the link and image

I couldnt properly understand your question. However I've made a JS FIDDLE. Hope this helps you. Since you've used $("#1").click() I assume you've used jQuery and I used the same in my code too.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/d4Fu2/3/)

html

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <table id="table1">
        <tr>
            <th>Table</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="javascript:;" rel="img1">Link1</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="javascript:;" rel="img2">Link2</a>
            </td>            
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<div id="box">
    <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/artdesigner/emoticons-2/256/cant-believe-it-icon.png" id="img1"/>
    <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/artdesigner/emoticons-2/256/too-much-icon.png" id="img2"/>
</div>
```

js

```
$('a').click(function(){
    imgid = $(this).attr('rel');
    $('a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');

    $('img').hide();    
    $('#'+imgid).fadeIn('slow');
});
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Great answer, works exactly how I want in jsfiddle, however, (this is going to sound really bad) how do I link the javascript as a separate document to the html? I tried saving the javascript as a javascript file, then replaced the hrefs to the location of the file, but when I preview it and click on the links, it shows the code for it in the browser, rather than just showing an image.

Answer (score 1):

You've got multiple issues going on here:

1. `1` is not a valid HTML `id` value for many browsers.  HTML 4 requirements for `id` values are:

   ```
   ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed
   by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"),
   colons (":"), and periods (".").
   ```

   This is the cause of the red background style not applying to the `td`.  HTML5 will eventually allow the value that you are using, but you will find many browsers not ready to support that fully.
2. You're images are both set to `visibility: hidden;`, but you never change that in your JS.  Neither image will ever display, until you set it's `visibility` value to `visible`, regardless of what its `z-index` value is.
3. Depending on the operating system where your assets are hosted, you **may** run into issues with your the file names of your images having spaces in them.  I would recommend not doing that . . . use and underscore instead of spaces, for example.

---

**UPDATE**

Actually, the issue with the `id` starting with a digit appears to be tied to CSS3 specifications for valid `id` selectors, rather than the HTML specification support.  According to the CSS3 spec, the selector must be a "CSS Identifier", which `. . . can contain only the characters [a-zA-Z0-9] and ISO 10646 characters U+00A0 and higher, plus the hyphen (-) and the underscore (_); they **cannot start with a digit**, two hyphens, or a hyphen followed by a digit.` (emphasis added)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the number issue or the spacing issue, however, microsoft expressions web, which I am writing all of it on, says I am working in html5 not 4, although changing it has fixed the issues.

Comment: One important thing to remember about HTML5 is that what really matters is what the browsers support. You can write perfectly valid HTML5 code, but if you view it in IE7, you are going to have issues.   :)

Comment: And, actually, the issue here, really appears to be the fact that CSS3 does not appear to support `id`s that start with numbers yet.  According to the spec (http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-css3-selectors-20110929/#id-selectors), CSS3 `id` selectors much be "CSS identifiers", the definition of which includes the following: `. . . can contain only the characters [a-zA-Z0-9] and ISO 10646 characters U+00A0 and higher, plus the hyphen (-) and the underscore (_); they cannot start with a digit, two hyphens, or a hyphen followed by a digit.`

Answer (score 0):

here's a working example, id of elements shouldn't start with a number though.

```
<div id="sidebar">
<table id="table1">
    <tr>
        <th>Table</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="d1">
            <div>
                <span>
                    Link 1
                </span>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```
$("#d1").click(function(){
    $("#one").css("visibility","visible");
})
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WmvqU/)